# Can I use GAM with multiple domains?

Tags: shell, google-workspace, gam

I need to run some GAM scripts across two domains as a client is migrating; is this possible?  I've been trying to find any documentation on setup but there doesn't seem to be :/

Any help is appreciated!

Note: This is not a question about primary or secondary domains - if you need more information on primary/secondary switching I've found [GAM3DirectoryCommands](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/wiki/GAM3DirectoryCommands) to be very helpful and descriptive!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not directly possible; however you can achieve this in the following manner:

- create a CONFIGS folder (you can actually call this wahtever makes sense to you), and a sub-folder for each domain
- move your *client_secrets.json*, *oauth2.txt* and *oauth2service.json* files from you GAM install folder into your newly-created domain folder
- run `gam info domain` and `gam info user` to see how this affected your gam install
- to create a new domain setup, run `gam create project`
- once complete, run `gam info domain` and `gam info user` again to see the difference
- remember to save your new config to your CONFIGS folder for this new domain too!
- when you've replaced the config files, run `gam user <your_admin_account_for_the_current_domain> check serviceaccount` before running any commands, otherwise you're likely to get some errors ;)

Now you can switch between domains by replacing *client_secrets.json*, *oauth2.txt* and *oauth2service.json* in your GAM install folder (and remember to `check serviceaccount`).

Obviously there are many more elegant ways to do this - but this will form the basis of your powershell script in any case ;P

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly easy, easier than the current answer in fact.
gam reads an OAUTHFILE environment variable which points to the access credentials (oauth2.txt by default). This is all that matters, as you can use the same GCP project for multiple domains.

So, all you need is an easy way to go around changing the OAUTFILE variable. I personally go with this gam alias (instead of the default alias in .bash_profile):

```
gam() { export OAUTHFILE=~/.local/share/gam/auth-$1.txt; shift; "~/.local/share/gam/gam" "$@" ; unset OAUTHFILE }
```

So my gam syntax now is

```
gam <something> info domain
```

No that above I use ~/.local/share/gam/... your paths might differ. Also you might want a $HOME/.gam-secrets and put them there.

Something is a simple string to uniquely identify each domain (it will be used for constructing the OAUTHFILE in the alias.

DO NOT forget to give your GCP service account access to all the domains (https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?#OGX:ManageOauthClients).

I can't think of a shorter path to gaving a multi-domain gam.